# CAMLQuery is not rendering title item from the list

Tags: javascript, caml-query, caml, query

Here is the list (please note 'Full Name' column has been changed to 'FullName' since I took this shot:
[image]

Here is the CAMLQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var camlQuery = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='ows_Branch' /><Value 
    Type='Choice'>Headquarters Support (MEAD)</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>";  

    $().SPServices({
        operation: "GetListItems",
        async: false,
        listName: "{E9E9983E-FECC-49DC-BA8D-4D0AE236C3C1}",
        CAMLQuery: camlQuery,
        CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='FullName' /></ViewFields>",
        completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
            $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
                var liHtml = "<span>" + $(this).attr("ows_FullName") + "</span>";
                $("#HSMEAD").append(liHtml);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

I just need to pull the full name from each branch and division and append it to a div. The caml query is not working but if i comment that out, the CAMLViewFields works fine and renders ALL the names from 'FullName' into the div correctly.

If there is a way to do it with JS without the query I am interested.

UPDATE:

with @Marko Tica's help, here is a final query that works for me:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $().SPServices({
    operation: "GetListItems",
    async: false,
    listName: "{E9E9983E-FECC-49DC-BA8D-4D0AE236C3C1}",
    CAMLQuery: "<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Column6' /><Value 
    Type='Choice'>Headquarters Support (MEAD)</Value></Eq></Where></Query>",
    CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields>  <FieldRef Name='FullName' /> 
    </ViewFields>",
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
      $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
         
       var liHtml = "<span>" + $(this).attr("ows_FullName") + "</span>";
           $("#HSMEAD").append(liHtml);

         });
       }
     });
    });
   </script>
```

Comment: Go to list > list settings> click on Branch column and in url you have Internal name of that column &Field=InternalNameOfBranchColumn. Put that internal name in query and add in viewfields (Title, Branch and Fullname)

Comment: that didn't do it for me...still wont render anything that looks like a query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `<View>` from query

Link
https://williamwmy.wordpress.com/2013/05/13/using-spservices-with-camlquery-to-get-listitems/

Comment: I used "column6" instead of branch, removed view but I think that link you have from wordpress is really good in setting up the query. I restructured my query using that and it all works!